# The derivation of the advection-diffusion equation uses $\nabla\cdot(c\vec{v})=(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)c$. Why doesn't the order of the derivative matter?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion, convection

In a derivation of the advection-diffusion equation, it is exploited that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot (c \vec{v}) =   ( \vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla})c$,  where $\vec{v}$ and c respectively are the velocity and the concentration. How can the order of the gradient not matter?

Comment: Work it out -- use the chain rule to expand the left hand side. What terms do you get? What assumptions are in your equations that allow you to keep or eliminate terms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $c$ and $\vec v$ is an arbitrary pair of functions, then the identity you wrote is false; instead it must read
$$
\nabla \cdot (c\vec v) = (\vec v\cdot \nabla) c + c (\nabla \cdot \vec v),
$$
which is easy to prove component-wise.

If your text is disregarding the second term, then presumably they're working under conditions where $\nabla \cdot \vec v = 0$. That's a natural assumption to have if $\vec v$ is the velocity field of an incompressible static flow, but you'll need to check your text for exactly what reasoning underlies that assumption.